# How to print an item in particular period which is under "while True:" loop

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I in this condition, 'Number of white and black pixels:' is printed millions of time owing to the loop. However, I want it to be printed every five seconds.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    low_p = np.array([136, 57, 0])
    high_p = np.array([255, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_p, high_p)
    p_mask= cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    number_of_white_pix = np.sum(mask == 255)
    number_of_black_pix = np.sum(mask == 0)

    print('Number of white pixels:', number_of_white_pix)
    print('Number of black pixels:', number_of_black_pix)

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Pink mask", mask) 
    cv2.imshow("original mask", p_mask) 
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27: 
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that using the time module. You can set `t1` as the start time and `t2` as the current time, updating every time the loop runs. Once `t1` and `t2` are 5 seconds apart, you can print the information and set the start time to `t2`. Here is the code that should work

```
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
t1 = time.time()
t2 = t1
while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()
    hsv_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    low_p = np.array([136, 57, 0])
    high_p = np.array([255, 255, 255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv_frame, low_p, high_p)
    p_mask= cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)

    number_of_white_pix = np.sum(mask == 255)
    number_of_black_pix = np.sum(mask == 0)

    if t2 - t1 >= 5:
        print('Number of white pixels:', number_of_white_pix)
        print('Number of black pixels:', number_of_black_pix)
        t1 = t2

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Pink mask", mask) 
    cv2.imshow("original mask", p_mask) 

    t2 = time.time()
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27: 
        break
```